# how to handle javascript pop up :seems like an alert window redirecting towards a url :having form fields

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

**Consider the following scenario:** I need to click on the link name **"testing"** (name field) which it opens a window (confusion is what type of window it is, as there are no maximize, minimize options)

1. this new window is not caught by `driver.getwindowhandle()`.
2. tried as an alert box, but still no response

**In current scenario of my code:** after I click on the **"testing"** link, the driver gets lost somewhere. Output of `system.out.println(driver);` does not get printed until I close the window.

I applied `thread.sleep(timeseconds)`, but again, no response.

What is the type of this window: containing text fields? How to get into it?

Step 1: Main Page

[image]

Step 2: (click on **"testing"** link => **Loading...**)

[image]

Step 3: (once loaded, new window appears)

[image]

Step 4: Here is the code: it returns no response after clicking on the link. It
does not catch the window using handle. New window page load takes hardly 
4 seconds.

[image]

Step 4: source code of pop up window -- seems like a frame 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a window.Its a frame.You will have to switch to frame using its id or name.Then go inside it and perform your actions and then switchToDefaultContent() to switch back from the frame

Comment: switch to frame ,  is not working. if you check the statement in the above attachment pa.tabularname.click(), once the link is clicked the driver gets lost somewhere. when i try to print the driver it does not get printed. as the driver is missing , thus not taking me to frame using ---driver.switchto()..